# Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload : User feedback before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

Using blueimp (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) I would like to be able to pause/stop the upload after the user starts it and then resume it.

What I want to achieve, is to show modals that ask questions to the user regarding the items he wants to upload. Using JS `confirm()` does work since it blocks the execution, but I want an alternative that uses an asynchronous approach.

I have seen the many events that the library offers, including `fileuploadstart`, but I don't see how I can abort or pause the upload from in there and restart it later on.

I have also thought of handling it when the upload button is clicked, but I use JS templates and I am not sure where the click event bindings happen for the uploader. Also, I would have to re-bind my events every time a file gets added (since each file has its own upload button).

Is this possible in a nicely-done way?

---

**EDIT:**

If I am to make it work by handling the button clicks, I will also need a way to access the file queue form outside the plug-in. I don't see how I can achieve this either... :(

---

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to get some API for the uploader, but I still don't see a way to access the file queue:

```
 $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload').options
```

[image: Uploader API]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. What I did was to ask the user when he added the files and I have inserted a property on each file object that reflected the user's choice.

This is the event for file addition: `fileuploadadded`.
And this (event) is where I have inserted the extra form field (that holds the user-chosen value): `fileuploadsubmit`.

As far as I saw, it is not possible to get a hold of the queue of that thing, so I have been updating my own queue using the event above.